# How to display a log to a textbox in realtime?

Tags: php, html

I want to do a realtime log for my Website so I see everything in the moment it happens.
I already got a log but I have to reload the page every time to update the content.

```
<?php
$logcontent = file_get_contents("log.txt", false);
?>

<html>

<textarea readonly class="logBox" cols="200" rows="40"> <?php echo($logcontent); ?> </textarea>

</html>
```

Comment: PHP is a server-side language. Once the script completes and browser receives its output, there isn't further interaction. If you really need real-time refreshing you need to use JavaScript and implement bidirectional communication (e.g. [web sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API))—though I feel that's not really what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

PHP scripts work only before page loading. If you want to do that you mean, you need to use AJAX.
For example your JS code:

```
setInterval(function(){
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.readyState === 4){
     var oglasi = xhr.responseText;
     document.getElementsByClassName("logBox").value = oglasi;
    }
   };

xhr.open('GET', 'YOUR LINK TO PHP FILE HERE');
xhr.send();
}, 3000);
```

And your code of PHP file:

```
<?
 $logcontent = file_get_contents("log.txt", false);
 echo $logcontent;
?>
```

More about setInterval here - [Window setInterval JS](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

More about AJAX here - [Making AJAX CALLS](https://dev.to/nikola/making-ajax-calls-in-pure-javascript-the-old-way-ed5)